# How would I add network routing instructions with NetworkManager in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, static-routes

I need some help with networking. I know how to do this in Windows, but not in NetworkManager on Arch Linux.

First my setup:

- NetworkManager
- Arch Linux

IP Addresses:

```
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+------------------------------+
| Address:      | Netmask:        | Gateway:      | Range IP is meant to access: |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+------------------------------+
| 192.168.0.28  | 255.255.255.0   | 192.168.0.1   | Everything except 172.*.*.*  |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+------------------------------+
| 172.25.73.162 | 255.255.255.248 | 172.25.73.161 |                              |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+------------------------------+
```

I know the Windows command is:

```
route -p ADD 172.16.0.0 MASK 255.240.0.0 172.25.73.161
```

I need to make all traffic go through `192.168.0.28`, and any traffic from or to `172.*.*.*` go through `172.25.73.162`.

Comment: yes, how I would add routing instructions in linux via networkmanager.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The route translates to `172.16.0.0/12 via 172.25.73.161`. So you can configure it in NM like this:

```
nmcli con modify "connection name" ipv4.routes "172.16.0.0/12 172.25.73.161"
```

Or use `nm-connection-editor` – under "IPv4 Settings" / "Routes", add `172.16.0.0` with netmask `255.240.0.0`, gateway `172.25.73.161`, and the default metric.

To add the route just temporarily, use:

```
ip route add 172.16.0.0/12 via 172.25.73.161
```

---

Also, your requirements contradict themselves.

172.16.0.0 with netmask 255.240.0.0 **is not the same thing** as "172.*.*.*" – the netmask only covers addresses **from 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255**.